# Building a string made easier?

Tags: php, strings

I have these lines of code in my view:

```
<?php
    $count = count($product->getTags());
    $tagsStr = '';
    foreach($product->getTags() as $key => $tag){
        $tagsStr.= " " . $tag->getTag();
        if(($key == 0 && $count < 1) || ($key == 0 && $count >1 && $key != $count)){
            $tagsStr .= ',';
        }
    } ?>
```

It prints strings like:

> Fish, Onions

Or

> Fish, Onions, Eggs

All these items are stored in an `ArrayCollection $product->getTags();`.

I find that these are a lot of lines for completing something this simple. I was wondering if you have ideas on simplifying this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tagsStr = implode(', ', array_map(function ($tag) { return $tag->getTag(); }, $product->getTags()->toArray()));
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work since getTags(); returns an array coellection of tag objects.

Comment: You are right we need to use an array_map call or something similar to get the real tags.

Comment: It should be noted that this answer relies on lambda functions, which may not always be available.

Answer (score 3):

Peter Kiss's code works, but it's not fast.

```
<?php

$tags = $product->getTags();
$c    = count($tags);
$str  = null;
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; ++$i) {
    if ($str) {
        $str .= ", ";
    }
    $str .= $tags[$i]->getTag();
}

?>
```

Yes, it’s not short (and not much different to your solution) but it’s highly efficient and therefor the solution I’d go for.

Comment: Also much more legible and backwards compatible as it does not rely on lambda functions +1